# How to remove duplicated content/value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

So, i have span element where i appending some content - sometimes this content is duplicated. How to remove this one value which is duplicate of another ...

This is how looks like my output html:

```
<span class="some_class">
   "value01" 
   "value01" 
   "value02" 
   "value03" 
   "value03" 
</span>
```

I can't add any function because i have no idea how to do this, can u help me?

Comment: I would modify the code that appends duplicated data.

Comment: hey man what you want to do ? describe briefly! You append data with the help of function, you want one more function to check whether the value exist before if yes, then not to append?

Comment: i need to check this span for content, if i have some duplicate values need to leave one of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are being added by JS code, then You can make sth like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sahadar/Nzs52/5/

You just have to make object which will store all strings placed inside this span, then just before insertion check if this inserted string is already in store object.

```
function(event) {
        var textareaValue = textarea.value();
        if(insertedTexts[textareaValue]) {
             event.preventDefault();
             textarea.value('');                         
         } else {
             insertedTexts[textareaValue] = true;
             someSpan.append("\""+textareaValue+"\"");
         }
    }
```

If these values are already inside span, use function as follows:

```
var someSpan = $('.some_class');
var insertedTexts = [];

var result = someSpan.text().match(/"\w+(?=\")/gm);
result = result.map(function(value) {
    return value.substring(1,value.length);
});
result.forEach(function(value) {
    if(insertedTexts.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        insertedTexts.push(value);
    }
});
var newSpanText = "\""+insertedTexts.join('""')+"\"";
someSpan.text(newSpanText);
console.info(result, insertedTexts);
```

It's rebuilding span text (trimming etc.) but main functinality is preserved.

jsFiddle working copy:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sahadar/kKNXG/6/

Comment: Use jsfiddle (sry, my change wasn't saved - there was little bug with else) - You need to modify this "button" thing if these values are added other way. It's only proposal.This will work only for cleared span (if You need to clear span which was earlier uglified then You need another solution).

Comment: ok, but i need to do this after content will added to span, this must be solution where i have filled span

Answer (score 0):

Create an array variable

```
var vals = [];
```

which keeps track of the items. Then, in your function that appends items to the span check:

```
if (vals.indexOf("Mynewvalue") > -1) {
  // Add to the span...
}
```